# Exponential equation - algebra

Tags: exponential-function

I’m having trouble solving this type of equations:

$y^{x} = k + x$

Where $x$ is the only unknown variable. 
I’ve tried substituting variables and all kind of things but I can never get to the answer.

The only way I’ve been able to solve for $x$ is by plotting $y^x$on a graph and plotting $k + x$ on the same graph and seeing where they intersect.

I’m trying to find a way of doing this without the need to draw it on a graph, if anyone has got any idea I’ll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Lambert W function can be applied here. This is a transcendental equation (with no elementary solutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) reduces the transcendental equation 
$$Xe^X=Y$$
to
$$X=W_n(Y),$$
where $n$ is the $n$th branch of $W$.

We use $W_n(\cdot)$ to solve this equation:
\begin{align*}
y^x&=k+x\\
e^{x\cdot\ln y}&=k+x\\
1&=(k+x)e^{-x\cdot\ln y}\\
-e^{-k}\ln y&=\big(\color{blue}{(-k-x)\ln y}\big)\cdot e^{\color{blue}{(-k-x)\ln y}}\\
W_n(-e^{-k}\ln y)&=\color{blue}{(-k-x)\ln y}\\
x&=-\frac{W_n(-e^{-k}\ln y)}{\ln y}-k.
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In line 4, we multiply $-e^{-k}\ln y$ on both sides (so as to transform to the form $Y=Xe^X$, where $X=\color{blue}{(-k-x)\ln y}$).
- In line 5, we use the property of $W$ function, i.e.
  $$Y=Xe^X\implies W_n(Y)=X.$$

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you went from step 3 to step 4 and from step 4 to step 5, thank you

Comment: @rr1303 answer updated, feel free to ask.

Comment: You can also find some examples [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Solutions_of_equations)

Comment: Perfectly understood, also thanks for the examples. One last thing, is it possible to find an actual solution(s) or do we simply leave it as a function of W? In Wikipedia that is what they do.

Comment: Yes, we leave $W$ in the answer, like what $\sin$ or $\ln$ do.